# mail settings for 2 different hosts (in one site)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

We have set our Web.config (for the site ecobrooms.company) in the following way:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <sectionGroup name="mailSettings">
      <section name="smtp_1" type="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection"/>
      <section name="smtp_2" type="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection"/>
      <section name="smtp_3" type="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <mailSettings>
    <smtp_1 deliveryMethod="Network" from="no.reply@ecobrooms.company">
      <network host="mail.ecobrooms.company" defaultCredentials="false" port="8889" userName="no.reply@ecobrooms.company" password="********" />
    </smtp_1>
    <smtp_2 deliveryMethod="Network" from="sale@ecobroomswebshop.com">
      <network host="mail.ecobroomswebshop.com" defaultCredentials="false" port="8889" userName="sale@ecobroomswebshop.com" password="********" /> 
    </smtp_2>
    <smtp_3 deliveryMethod="Network" from="mail3@temp.uri">
      <network host="..." defaultCredentials="false"/>
    </smtp_3>
  </mailSettings>

  ...
</configuration>
```

When we try to send an email with smtp_2:

```
using (SmtpClient SmtpKlijent = new SmtpClient(smtpSection.Network.Host, smtpSection.Network.Port))
                    {
                        MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage();
                        Mail.From = new MailAddress("sale@ecobroomswebshop.com");

                        Mail.To.Add(email);

                        Mail.CC.Add("no.reply@ecobrooms.company");

                        Mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        Mail.Subject = Subject;
                        Mail.Body = poruka;

                        try
                        {
                            SmtpKlijent.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                            SmtpKlijent.EnableSsl = false;
                            SmtpKlijent.Send(Mail);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBoxGl.Show((Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler, "Please double check the From Address and Password to confirm that both of them are correct.");
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }
```

we get the following error:

**Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: no.reply@ecobrooms.company No such user here**

(for smtp_1 works fine)

Are we trying to do impossible?
Please help!